# SoundPool rate out of range

Tags: android, soundpool

I've got a problem with SoundPool. I've tried to load some file but `SoundPool` gave to me error `Sample rate (192000) out of range`. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main trouble of  this was in audio files. I couldn't add file more than 256 kb. Tried to compress audio files and now it works fine.